# finding the LCM using python

Tags: python, lcm

def multiple(a, b):
    """so I'm trying to return the smallest number n that is a multiple of both a and b.

for example:

> > > multiple(3, 4)
> > >           12
> > >       multiple(14, 21)
> > >           42
> > >           """

```
def gcd (a,b):
    if a < b : a , b = b,a
    while b:
        a , b = b , a % b
    return a

def lcm (a , b):
    n= (a*b) / gcd(a,b)
    return n
```

it keeps throwing errors about indentation and logic. I don't understand why. I've tried changing the variables around too.

Comment: Your code works as is.

Comment: Yeah your code works. I tried in Python 3. so what's the issue?

Comment: Can not reproduce, seems like a 'tab and space' issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to find GCD, we can directly find LCM. Below code works

```
def lcmof(x,y):
    res=0
    mx=max(x,y)
    mn=min(x,y)
    for i in range(1,mx+1,1):
        temp=mx*i
        try:
            if(temp%mn==0):
                res=temp
                break
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            res=0
            break
    return res
```

Comment: For large values of x and y, this is much slower than the approach given in the question, which is of order log(min(x,y)).

Comment: Ok, this did not work for me, i put 32 and 16 and it should put out 2 ( aka 2**5 is 32 and 2**4 is 16 ) it gave me a 16 as final result.